# What do the following icons mean when creating a new workitem in TFS 2012?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012, tfs-workitem

The following image is in spanish but that does not  matter.

The menu shows the list of workitems on the TFS and opens when I click on "create new work item". What I don't know is what mean the different icons and why the first two workitemtypes have a different one.

I created all the workitems you can see there but I wasn't aware of doing anything different on them that could set a different icon nor a different place on the menu.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These icons represent what category those specific work item types are in. For instance, the clipboard with the check corresponds to a work item type that is in the task category and the one below it with the chat box and an exclamation point represents a work item type that is in the requirements category. These categories are defined in the process template when creating a team project, and they can also be exported/edited/imported to any current project. Hope this helps :)

Here is the MSDN link on customizing categories: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd273721.aspx

Comment: Amazing, I will check it tomorrow.